# How to know if someone voted to close my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I guess somebody voted to close my question but I didn't not get any notification about it. I guess because another person has commented on my question about it.

Comment: Unless 5 others agreed, that information isn't disclosed. Probably for good reasons. Why do you need to know actually?

Comment: I was upset someone voted to close my question without any comment. It was a good question that got 2 upvotes within minutes after I posted it.

Comment: Instead of _getting upset_, it's probably better to start reasoning how you could improve your question.

Comment: If you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508916/which-is-the-latest-version-of-jdk-1-7, then in whose view is it a 'good question'?  Some voters obviously thought it was not a good question, and downvoted it.  It' a software search query and don't think it has much lasting value for the SO knowledge repository, so I also down and close voted it.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: I hope you are not talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31508916/2564301). It does not really show any research effort – I assume "Am not finding any link to download jdk 1.7.0_85" is to mean, "I typed exactly this into one search engine and it Did Not Work".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get yourself up to 250 points and gain the [*View Close Votes* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

You will not get *notified* of close votes, however.